# Text not displaying at the proper position in a div

Tags: css

The username is not displaying in the correct position within the div properly. It is displaying outside the div element. I have tried changing the text-align property but that is not working. I don't want to change the `.rclick` class because it is being used for another element which works properly. How can I use an additional class?

php code

```
echo "<div class=\"rclick\" title=\"{$user}\"  style=\"width: auto;\">";

            if (strlen($user) > 10) 
                {
                    $user = wordwrap($user, 10);
                    $user = substr($user, 0, 10);
                echo "Hi {$user}...";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "Hi {$user}";              
                }
                echo "</div>";
```

css code

```
#nav .rclick {
position: relative;
left: 500px;
top: 40px;
width: 250px;
height: 28px;
background: url(../images/Employer.jpg) no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1.14em;
}
```

[image: showing text in black color]

Comment: If you right-click on the div element in Chrome developer tools/Firebug and inspect, can you post the HTML that is generated?

Comment: As this is a front-end issue, can you show us the generated HTML? the PHP isn't really that much help.

Comment: `<div class="rclick" title="monika" style="width: auto;">Hi monika</div>`

Comment: Why are you inlining `width: auto` when the css definition has a width? The `auto` will override the width in the css

Comment: text was coming at bottom of div element using `width =250px` when i used inlining `width: auto ` than text came to the right of div element ,but not within the div element

Comment: Have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure good separation of presentation and content, I would suggest removing the inline style rule from your HTML markup and use CSS to define all of your style declarations.

Because of the cascading nature of CSS, inline styles in HTML markup will override equivalent declarations within `<style>` tags in an HTML page, which will in turn override declarations within an external stylesheet.

If you want to apply more than one class to your element, you can apply them both, like so:

```
#nav .customrule
{
    /*extra style definitions*/
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<div class="rclick customrule" title="monika">Hi monika</div>
```

Because you're relatively positioning the div, you could wrap the text in a span and absolutely position it within the div to place it in the position that you require:

```
<div class="rclick" title="monika"><span>Hi monika</span></div>

#nav .rclick span
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

The origin for the span will be the first relatively positioned container, which in your case is the containing div.

I have added a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/52MH8/1/) demonstrating this.

Comment: i tried it using span ,and when did inspect element in browser ,it is taking this css rule only`#nav .rclick {
color: rgb(22, 16, 16);
font-size: 1.14em;
}` and not which i added for span ,why is it so,i have added image in my question to show how text appear

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML and all the css that you've added? Best update your question rather than posting in comments